# Odd include errors building using Ubuntu SDK

Tags: 14.04, dbus

I'm trying to write a scope in 14.04 that makes DBus calls to Pidgin. I use
`#include <qt5/QtDBus/qdbusinterface.h>`
as one of the include statements but when I build my project I get an error outside the project.

```
/usr/include/qt5/QtDBus/qdbusinterface.h:45: error: QtDBus/qdbusabstractinterface.h: No such file or directory #include <QtDBus/qdbusabstractinterface.h>
```

It seems the headers do not reflect the same include path for QtDbus

```
#include <QtDBus/qdbusabstractinterface.h>
```

So how can I adjust for this in my project? I'm using Ubuntu SDK.

Comment: Maybe you should add CONFIG += qdbus in *.pro file?

Comment: Do you know how I'd do that using the Ubuntu SDK "QT Creator"

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using cmake instead of qmake, try this:

find_package(Qt5DBus 5.2 REQUIRED)

Comment: this didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
#include <QDBusInterface>
#include <QDBusConnection>
```

Comment: it's not my code that's causing the error. the header file I'm calling is outside my code project but seems to reference QtDBus differently than how Ubuntu SDK requires it. See in my code the include statement path starts with <qt5/QtDBus/.....> but the header being called also has references in it to QtDBus headers that have an include path like this <QtDBus/......> and cmake is not able to find that path. I could easily edit the headers outside the project but that isn't how it should be fixed.